# Wagtail raises ValidationError on page update

Tags: python, django, wagtail, validationerror

On publishing updates to an existing wagtail page it raises a ValidationError with the message below.

`ValidationError({'live_revision': ['page revision instance with id 33 does not exist.']})`

All other actions such as drafting, submitting for moderation all work okay.
Only publishing the page with new updates raises the ValidationError effectively limiting the ability to update existing pages.

Answer (score 2):

Just faced a very similar issue.

Make sure you are not using `ParentalKey` in a `Page` model.
Use the regular Django `models.ForeignKey` instead.

Comment: this answer is correct, do not know why it was unaccepted