# Wagtail ValidationError on publish (page revision instance does not exist)

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

We are facing an issue with Wagtail. Whenever one makes an edit to a page and selects "Publish", they are faced with a `ValidationError` with the message `{'live_revision': ['page revision instance with id 74 does not exist.']}` (see screenshot). This only seems to occur when the page is in "Draft" status, though I cannot confirm that this always holds.

When I view the page revisions, I can confirm that a revision with ID 74 does indeed not exist. My question is, how might this have occurred, how can we fix it so that we are able to publish the page currently, and what can we do to prevent this from occurring in future? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

[image]

I am aware of a similar question on StackOverflow that has already received an answer ([Wagtail raises ValidationError on page update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51928023/6208351)), however this answer does not help in our situation as we are not using `ParentalKey` in any of our models.